# SAP NCo x64 Visual Studio 2013 VB aspx page directive error

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2013, sap-dotnet-connector

I have had a website up and running for over 3 years with SAP .NET Connector 3.0 in 32 bit format.  Unfortunately the Windows 2003 server that was hosting this application has failed.  Our network team has created a new Windows 2012 server,  and request the website be re-written   in 64 bit.  I have successfully  added the reference to the x64 version of sapnco dll's,  but now when I try to compile website, I'm getting an error on my page directive.

<%@ Page Language="VB" AutoEventWireup="false" CodeFile="NewAni.aspx.vb" Inherits="NewAni" %>

The error is "ASP.NET Runtime error: Object reference not set to instance of an object"

None of the code itself (ECCDestConfig.vb and code behinds) does not show any errors.  This error is appearing on the page directive of ALL my .aspx web pages in this project, even pages that don't call SAP.

I have set the configuration manager to use x64 as the active solution platform.

I am really stuck - and could use some help.

Answer (score 0):

SAP .NET Connector needs Microsoft Visual C++ runtime of a specific version, which depends on both the .NET framework version and the version of the Operating System (32-bit or 64-bit).

According to the SAP official documentation, you need one of the followings:

- NCo 3.0 32-bit (x86), .NET 2.0 (also 3.0, and/or 3.5): **Microsoft Visual C++ 2008 Redistributable Pack (x86) (mscvp80.dll)**
- NCo 3.0 64-bit (x64), .NET 2.0 (also 3.0, and/or 3.5): **Microsoft Visual C++ 2008 Redistributable Pack (x64) (mscvp80.dll)**
- NCo 3.0 32-bit (x86), .NET 4.0: **Microsoft Visual C++ 2010 Redistributable Pack (x86) (mscvp100.dll)**
- NCo 3.0 64-bit (x64), .NET 4.0: **Microsoft Visual C++ 2010 Redistributable Pack (x64) (mscvp100.dll)**

Answer (score 0):

Problem solved.  I used VB in Visual Studio 2013 with the 64 bit SAP .nco .  The problem was I had created a "website" not a new "project.  Once I did, and loaded the SAP DLL's as references to the project,  and changed the configuration to use x64,  new web pages I added did so without error.  I might note, I aslo installed SAP GUI 730 on the same server.  Its working now, both interacting with SAP and a separate SQL database,

Thanks for your answer

Answer (score 0):

To be able to execute the x64 dlls in VStudio, it must be verified that the project is being compiled also in x64. You have to go to Tools, Options ..., Projects and Solutions, Web Projects. And check "Use the 64 bits."[image]